# Express/Typescript + Jest + Supertest + TypeORM - Random Timeout Exception & Memory Leak

Tags: typescript, express, jestjs, supertest

I am attempting to write unit tests for an express API. Each test suite creates a new instance of an express server before the tests.

When each test suite is run independently there seems to be no issues, when run together I am seeing a few issues.

After 9 test suites complete, each individual test seems to output the following warning:

```
(node:5282) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 connection listeners added to [Server]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
    at _addListener (node:events:453:17)
    at Server.addListener (node:events:469:10)
    at Server.<anonymous> (node_modules/async-listener/index.js:90:10) => this.on('connection', function (socket) {...
    at Server.<anonymous> (node_modules/async-listener/index.js:97:23) => return original.apply(this, arguments);
    at Server.<anonymous> (node_modules/async-listener/index.js:97:23)
    at Server.<anonymous> (node_modules/async-listener/index.js:97:23)
    at Server.<anonymous> (node_modules/async-listener/index.js:97:23)
    at Server.<anonymous> (node_modules/async-listener/index.js:97:23)
    at Server.<anonymous> (node_modules/async-listener/index.js:97:23)
    at Server.<anonymous> (node_modules/async-listener/index.js:97:23)
```

I am not interested in just suppressing this warning especially if this relates to a memory leak so please don't suggest this.

A few random (it seems) tests will sometimes fail with the error:

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 20000 ms for a test.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

I am certain this does not relate to the specified timeout value since these tests will succeed in less than 500ms and the tests will fail no matter that the timeout value is set to.

**Example .test.ts File**

```
import Server from '../../server';
import { generateTestData } from '../generate-database-data';

import * as request from 'supertest';
import { APIRoutes } from '../../routes';

const server = new Server(); // New instance of express server

describe('API Test', () => {

    // Sets up TypeORM DB connection
    beforeAll(async() => await server.connect());

    // Run raw sql statements using typeorm query runner to truncate and populate fresh data for each test case
    beforeEach(async () => await generateTestData(server.connection));

    // Close TypeORM connection after all tests
    afterAll(async () => await server.connection.close());
    
    test('Get All', async () => {
        const response = await request(server.app)
          .get(APIRoutes.ROUTE)
          .set('Accept', 'application/json');

        expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
        expect(response.body.length).toEqual(4);
    });

    ...

});
```

**Server.ts**

```
import * as express from 'express';
import 'express-async-errors';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { configureRoutes } from './routes';

require('dotenv').config({path: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? '.env.test' : '.env'});

class Server {

    public app: express.Application;
    public server;
    public connection;

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.configuration();
    }

    public configuration() {
        this.app.set('port', process.env.PORT);
        this.app.use(express.json());
    }

    public async connect() {
        this.connection = await createConnection({
            'type': 'mysql',
            'host': process.env.DB_HOST,
            'port': parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
            'username': process.env.DB_USERNAME,
            'password': process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
            'database': process.env.DB_DATABASE,
            'dropSchema': process.env.DB_DROP_SCHEMA === 'true',
            'synchronize': true,
            'logging': ['error'],
            'logger': 'file',
            'entities': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? ['src/entities/**/*.ts'] : ['build/src/entities/**/*.js'],
            'cli': { 'entitiesDir': 'build/src/entities' },
            'extra': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? {
                'connectionLimit': 0
            } : {},
        });
        configureRoutes(this.app);
        return
    }

    public async start() {
        await this.connect();
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
            this.server = this.app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
                console.log(`App listening on the port ${process.env.PORT}`);
            });
        }
    }

    public async stop() {
        await this.server?.close();
        await this.connection?.close();
    }
}

// start express server
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    const server = new Server();
    server.start();
}

export default Server;
```

**Related Dependancies**

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.18",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest": "^27.2.0",
    "jest-express": "^1.12.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.6",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.5.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "helmet": "^5.0.2",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.42"
  }
```

I don't believe this is an issues relating to typeorm and the database connection since I can remove the connection along with the queries that generate the test data and some tests will still fail with the same timeout error and warning message.
Based on the warning message `at Server.addListener (node:events:469:10)` this prompts me to believe this error relates to either the express server or supertest.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

The 2 issues do not seem to be related - I believe I have found a solution to the timeout error issue.

The issue seems to have been a result of how the DB connection was being established through typeorm.

I removed the database connection logic from the express server and initialized it independently in a `setupFilesAfterEnv` file. In the `beforeAll` function I create the connection if a current connection does not exist. If a current connection exists, I call the `.connect()` method.

I have a script running to run the tests indefinitely with no error cases in the past hour so I am confident that issue is resolved.

I am still seeing the `MaxListenersExceededWarning` warning, however.

Comment: Try to comment the beforeAll and afterAll section. Supertest doesn't require you to manually start the server before the tests execution. Maybe the timeout is related with that.